# Econometric Filter Evaluation

Tags: econometrics

My undergraduate Thesis includes mainly filtering process evaluation. Due to the word limit (low limit), I just realised I have to include more filters than Christiano Fitzgerald (CF) and wavelets.

I consider the following filters:

1. hodrick prescott
2. Baxter King
3. Butterworth
4. trigonometric regression

Since it's an evaluation of filtering processes, I don't really care if a filter is better or worse, rather than the justification. I cannot find any resource which compares directly filters.

Could you explain to me the pros and cons of those filters in comparison with CF? I would appreciate if there is any resource, but it is not mandatory.